# How to programatically import libraries in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I am using brace and i am importing multiple modes from it. Like below

```
import 'brace/mode/javascript';
import 'brace/mode/java';
.
.
.
import 'brace/mode/python';
```

Is there any way i can do this programatically like following

```
languages.forEach(language => {
    import `brace/mode/${language}`;
});
```